# Error using VideoReader/init (line 619) MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use VideoReader in Matlab R2016a in Ubuntu 16.04 to read a .mp4 file but it gives me error as follows:

```
>> VideoReader('Bleach.mp4');
Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)
Failed to initialize internal resources.

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);
```

I get the same error when trying to read an .avi file using the same. Please help me fix the problem.

Comment: I don't think Matlab decodes videos itself. It relies on external codecs. Do you have the dependencies [suggested by the Matlab docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-video-file-formats.html)?

Comment: You may need to install `gstreamer`.  http://uniqueminds.co/2013/08/12/how-to-install-gstreamer-0-10-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: First of all, thank you for replying. I fixed the issue for .mp4 files by installing gstreamer libraries. But the issue persists for .mpg format files. Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it worked for me.

I downloaded K-lite full coded pack from [this page](https://filehippo.com/download_klite_codec_pack/) and installed it with Media Player Classic being the install option. It downloaded all the necessary codec packages and VideoReader was able to read `.avi`, or `.mp4` that previously failed to load.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33082867/712452) is the answer that explained it where I learn this.